# using wpdb instead of wp_query to improve website loading for massive database wp_posts

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I have a [website](https://akhbarejadid.com/) with massive database volume that is almost 4Gb and have almost 200k posts. As I check my website loading I see a 4-6 second loading of main page and that is because I use `wp_query` for many custom_post_type and **I think using `wp_query` call all rows of `wp_posts` table** and that's why website loading is too slow.

So I searched too many articles and find out **maybe using wpdb query is better than wp_query to just call a few posts at the first time**.I mean if I have 200k post, Everytime users load main page the code just recall only 10 or 20 rows of `wp_posts` table and It will very faster than call all 200k post to display 10 or 20 post.

For now I am using this code:

```php
<?php
                    $last = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_status' =>'publish',
                        'post_type' =>'post',
                        'cat' => 2365,
                        'posts_per_page' =>12,                      
                    )); if($last->have_posts()) : while($last->have_posts()) : $last->the_post(); ?>
```

I want to know how can I use wpdb query for above code to make my website's loading faster?

I would glad to hear your opinion about how can I improve my website loading for calling posts in main page?

Comment: another idea is using wpdb to just call today posts instead of all date posts! I am waiting for your answer about these two ways

Comment: Using WPDB will **not** make this faster, and can even make it significantly slower on some hosts. The articles you read were incorrect, and the theory that it will call all 200k posts is incorrect. I would instead suggest looking into the `pre_get_posts` filter to avoid making the query entirely